# Alternative to 'ls -A' in Bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, bash-scripting, ls

Is there an alternative to `ls -A` command in native bash functions?
Wildcard `*` isn't the same. I tried hard to find one, but `echo *` doesn't show hidden files.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
shopt -s dotglob
echo *
```

---

See: `help shopt` and `shopt`

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to [Cyrus' answer](https://superuser.com/a/948916/461558), you could also loop over and print all directory contents in one line:

`for file in {.*,*}; do echo "$file"; done`

However, this is *slightly* different from `ls -A` as it includes `.` and `..`; but may still be of use.

Comment: To avoid a `*` as result in an empty directory feel free to add `shopt -s nullglob`